# How to rearrange boxes automatically using nearest position in an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, overlap, bounding-box

I have two bound boxes. one for predict, which contains 3 rows
the second for ground truth that contains two rows.

Ground truth boxes (*x,y,w,h*)

```
[[210, 98, 103, 88],
 [62, 75, 150, 120]]
```

Predicate boxes (*x,y,w,h*)

```
[[218, 104, 94, 69],
 [154 ,184, 34, 9],
 [67, 77, 143, 100]]
```

If I need to compute the bounding box overlap ratio using MATLAB function [bboxOverlapRatio](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/bboxoverlapratio.html). The function evaluates the first-row box of ground truth with the first row in the predicate. Then second-row of ground truth evaluates with the second-row from predicate boxes. The function evaluates
bound boxes using sequentially techniques row by row. **The question is:** What is a function that rearranges predicate boxes using the nearest position(place) or resorts boxes automatically by their appearance in the image? I want to rearrange to have a high ratio.

How can I do this if there is no MATLAB function?

Here is a sample code:

```
groundTruth = [210  98  103 88, 62  75  150 120]
predicate = [218 104 94 69, 154 184 34  9, 67 77 143 100];
ratio = bboxOverlapRatio(groundTruth,predicate)
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: According to [this](https://it.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/bboxoverlapratio.html), the bboxOverlapRatio finds the *overlap ratio between each pair of bounding boxes*. In your example, if the GT boxes have 2 rows, and PR boxes have 3 rows, the output should contain 6 elements ( for each pair ).

Comment: Yes exactly. I need to to compare pairs not sequentially.  I need to compare as location of first point in the box. When I run the code by this sequence of pair  I get ratio [0.71  0   0, 0  0.017   0.79]. But when I run the code by location of the first point in box. The predicate sequential will differ. The point(67,77) , row 3 in predicate must be chosen, because it is near to point (62,75) of the ground truth value,  row 2, bound box lable.

Comment: The ratio will be [0.71  0   0,0   0.79   0.170] as to second change. When compare row 2 from ground truth with row 3 from predicate

Comment: What do you meant by *I run the code by location of the first point in box*? The ratios provide information regarding which boxes overlap more and which don't. The first coordinate ( row 1 ) has different ratios with different boxes, and you pick the one with the max ratio. The last value of your ratio array (0.79) signifies the ratio between (67,77) rectangle and (62,75 ) rectangle. This is sufficient information to conclude that these two overlap the most.

Comment: I mean if I change between the two boxes according to what I saw when compared the point (67,77) and (62,75). I could pick them manually because two points are near to each.

Comment: How to pick 0.79 not 0.170 from the out put matrix ratio?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation of the function [bboxOverlapRatio](https://it.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/bboxoverlapratio.html),

*Each (I, J) element in the output matrix corresponds to the overlap ratio between row I in bboxA and row J in bboxB*.

For the function, your first argument (bboxA) is `groundTruth` and bboxB is `predicate`. Hence, in the ratio array, the element `[0,1]` represents the overlap ratio between `grountTruth[0]` and `predicate[1]`. Thus, for `groundtruth[1]`, you can iterate through `[1,0], [1,1], [1,2]` and find the maximum value among them. Since `[1,2]` is the maximum, this indicates that for row 1 in groundTruth, row 2 in predicate has the highest value.

This might be useful - [max](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html), especially the section **Return Linear Indices**.

Comment: Your answer save my life.  Thank you very much. I used diag ()function to pick the ratio matrix value. The algorithm I design get an a prity  accuracy. I will apply the max function to increase accuracy of algorithm